# Symfony2 - Call the same getRepository in all controller actions

Tags: symfony, controller, symfony-2.3

I'm using a repository in Symfony2-controller like this:

```
$blog = $em->getRepository('BlogBloggerBundle:BlogData')->getBlogData($id);
```

Before I call it into the twig view through an array.

All works right but the issue is that it make up a footer menu, then, i should call it almost in every action which i need.

How i can call it from a "common" repository every time which i need?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Create a view reponse listener registering a twig variable and add the repository call in there...

... or create a twig extension exposing the data received from the repository as a global twig variable.

... or (my preferred choice) create a controller dedicated to rendering the footer and include the footer like this:

```
{{ render(controller('Bundle:controller:action')) }}
```

Read more about rendering fragments in [this blog post](http://symfony.com/blog/new-in-symfony-2-2-the-new-fragment-sub-framework) on the symfony homepage.

Comment: good idea. I'm loading data from a repository:
`$brand = $em->getRepository('BloggerBlogBundle:BlogData')->getBlogData($id);
return $brand);`
And i get this error:
`an exception has been thrown during the rendering of a template ("The controller must return a response (Array(0 => Array(0 => Array .... `

Comment: `);` seems to be a syntax error shouldn't it be `return $brand;` ?

Comment: As you're trying to return the entity directly and not a `Response` object ... did you add the `@View` annotation to your controller ... or do you have some other controller response listener (i.e. FOSUserBundle's) in place ? ... Otherwise your need to do something like this:  `return $this->render(
    'BloggerBlogBundle:Footer:index.html.twig',
    array('brand' => $brand)
);`

Comment: Thanks a lot [nifr](http://stackoverflow.com/users/1832745/nifr)!!! Finally i solved it!
I lost the `$this->render( 'Blogger...` part.
With yours suggestions it works perfectly!

Answer (score 0):

FYI Official documentation about embedding controllers : http://symfony.com/doc/current/book/templating.html#embedding-controllers